# how to lower postfix smtp idle timeout to 5s?

Tags: postfix

I am trying to (temporarily) lower `smtpd_policy_service_max_idle` on postfix 2.3.8 from 300s to 5s to debug a possible client-side problem. The following seem to state that my change is accepted, but when I purposely leave the client idly connected for >> 5 seconds I don't see a timeout disconnect message in mail.log that I used to see when the value was 300s.

```
sudo postconf -ve smtpd_policy_service_max_idle=5s; sudo postconf | grep _idle
ipc_idle = 100s
max_idle = 100s
smtpd_policy_service_max_idle = 5s
```

Do I need to restart postfix to for the setting to take effect? Is there another timeout value that provides a (higher) lower bound?

thanks
-nikita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, config settings in main.cf don't take effect until you restart (or at least tell Postfix to reload the config).

Comment: Yep, I issued exactly the commands cited in my original post and now see the following in main.cf: 'smtpd_policy_service_max_idle = 5s'. However, even after doing 'postfix reload' and 'postfix stop; postfix start' the idle timeout observed in testing is still 300s. 

How do I debug this? Is there another setting that overrides 'smtpd_policy_service_max_idle'?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was twiddling the wrong param - `smtpd_timeout` turned out to be the right one.